# How can I pull out date & location that doesn't have its own tag and put into separate tags?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I want to create an RSS feed using Yahoo! Pipes. The feed source coming from a website in XML format doesn't have a date/time in its own tags for every item. How can I pull out this content (date & location event) and put it in 2 tags using Yahoo Pipes? The content is in `<description>` tag.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[ 2013/11/06 @ Polytechnique Montréal - Pavillon Lassonde<br/><br/>
    ...
</description>
```

Can anyone show me how to do this using Yahoo! Pipes?